# IOS SimpleFTPExample - upload multiple images

Tags: ios, ftp

I am really new here. Can someone guide me to modify the SimpleFTPExample from Apple to upload multiple files. As in the example i can upload 1 image now.

Should I use threads? or any other way?

some examples are greatly appreciated!

SimpleFTPExample - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If like ftp, the -i argument disables interactive prompting during transfers of multiple files. Again, if like ftp, to transfer multiple files, after establishing a connection, you'd use mput or mget, and wildcards.

```
ftp -i ftp://remote.server.ftp

mput directory/*

mget remote_directory/*files.mp?
```

Comment: Hi chillin,Thank you for the answer but I am not really clear on your explanation. could you provide more details to do it in iOS?